# How to define the event handler in another class?

Tags: c#

I tried to define the `UploadStringCompleted` of `Webclient` outside the class `PanelAPI`, so I define a variable `requestTokenCompleted`.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Net;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace Shadowsocks.Controller
{
    class PanelAPI
    {
        private string baseURL = "https://test.com/api";
        public event UploadStringCompletedEventHandler requestTokenCompleted;
        public event DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler requestServersCompleted;

        public void requestToken(string email, string passwd)
        {
            var logInfo = new { email = email, passwd = passwd };
            WebClient client = new WebClient();

            Uri uri = new Uri($"{baseURL}/token");

            client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/json";

            client.UploadStringCompleted += requestTokenCompleted;
            client.UploadStringAsync(uri, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(logInfo));
        }


    }
}
```

Now I tried to implement `requestTokenCompleted` in the `Authform` class. But `requestTokenCompleted` is not executed when I call `api.requestToken()`. How can I fix it？

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using Shadowsocks.Controller;
using Shadowsocks.Model;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows.Forms;


namespace Shadowsocks.View
{
    public partial class AuthForm : Form
    {
        public AuthForm(ShadowsocksController controller)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void AuthForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void LoginButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var _config = Configuration.Load();
            _config.userProfile.email = emailTextBox.Text;
            _config.userProfile.passwd = pwdTextBox.Text;

            Configuration.Save(_config);

            var api = new PanelAPI();

            api.requestTokenCompleted += requestTokenCompleted;
            api.requestToken(emailTextBox.Text, pwdTextBox.Text);
        }

        private void requestTokenCompleted(Object sender, UploadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("requestTokenCompleted");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The method actually works, I just missed something.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't actually firing the `requestTokenCompleted` event from the `requestToken()` method.

You need:

```
if (requestTokenCompleted != null)
    requestTokenCompleted(this, new UploadStringCompletedEventArgs());
```

Put this wherever in your method you want the handlers to receive the event notification.

---

EDIT: Sorry, to be clear, there are two things going on here.

There are two different events at play in this example. The first is the event defined on the client. This is something you don't control, and in your API code you need to handle it in order to know when the client is complete.

The second event is the one you declare and control, using it to notify your downstream customer (in this case the `AuthForm`) of the completion of its work. It's important to understand that this event *can* be of the same type as the underlying `WebClient` event, but it doesn't have to be.

So you will be first handling the webclient event. Here's one way you can do this:

```
    public void requestToken(string email, string passwd)
    {
        var logInfo = new { email = email, passwd = passwd };
        WebClient client = new WebClient();

        Uri uri = new Uri($"{baseURL}/token");

        client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/json";

        client.UploadStringCompleted += client_requestCompleted; // NOTE THE CHANGE
        client.UploadStringAsync(uri, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(logInfo));
    }

    private void client_requestCompleted(Object sender, UploadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Here is where you will want to chain out to your custom event.
        // In this example I simply pass the original completion event args
        if (requestTokenCompleted != null)
            requestTokenCompleted(this, e);
    }
```

Note that I'm not wiring up the original event to the client's handler, I'm just handling the event like I would any other event. Then, I fire the second event off in a chained fashion.

To get around the lack of a public constructor, here I simply pass the one I got from the client on to the `AuthForm`'s handler. But since I control the event entirely, I could instead use an entirely different event type (change the signature of the delegate to take a vanilla `EventArgs`, or a totally custom argument type.

You'll need to choose which method works best for you. I personally would prefer to change the argument type so that my public contract doesn't expose the implementation detail of being based on `WebClient`, but it might be fine for you.

Comment: For some reason this does not work for me. Says `'UploadStringCompletedEventArgs' does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments.`

Comment: Them it sounds like you need to pass something inside the `new UploadStringCompletedEventArgs()` part. Look at the definition of that class and constructor to find out what is expected.

Comment: If you look at the source code, you'll see that the constructor is [marked as `internal`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/Net/webclient.cs,7705515fed7e92e4) and there is indeed no constructor that takes 0 argument.

Comment: Is there a static member on the class, like `.Empty`? In this case, you control both the event declaration and the code that handles the event, so you could just change it to a generic `EventArgs`, or a custom argument class. If you really don't need to pass anything, you can eliminate that argument from the delegate type altogether. Will anything you don't control be using this?

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't being very clear. See the updated answer for more detail.